# Using :focus and tabindex to toggle a drop down?

Tags: html, css, tabindex

Some of you might know this way of displaying a drop down menu:

Give the parent the tabindex-attribute so that you can hide or show a child element with 'parent:focus child' inside CSS.

It sounds a little bit "hackish" to me, so I just wanted to know if someone can tell me if using this is cool or not cool.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't just target the menu itself rather than its parent.

Comment: maybe this old pen of mine can help you http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/dsvwF accordeon menu with tabindex+focus aside a similar menu with input . you can test the behaviors of each and find out what you really need ...  javaScript is usually used for this kind of jobs/interactions.

Comment: @MrLister :target and :focus do have different behaviors, loosing the focus, adjacent or child can be hidden again, :target needs a reload . :focus seem much closer to what javaScript can do. :focus + tabindex allow as well to use the tab key.  Something wich should require javascript : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/gxcJj (tab can open and go through the menu via :focus (click or tab and of course :hover :) )  It should not be done only via CSS anyway.

Comment: It can be cool if your site is for a special public for wich it will work and will seem cool, for a regular website, Use javaScript to make sure it works everywhere :) . No one will know if it is css or js unless they go look in your code ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus I didn't mean `:target`...

Comment: @MrLister, i guessed so, but to focus the element to hide is not really a css option ;) , target was kind of the option left ...

Comment: well, I'm glad that to see a discussion already! But actually I'm not looking for a solution, it was just an example. Just wanted to know if abusing the tabindex on div elements to enable some kind of interaction is "legal" HTML/CSS or is it more like a hack?

Comment: well it is "legal" since it is in the spec (and for ages). tabindex  can help to go through the page via tab, it can be usefull for some users. but for complex styling/interaction, it is javaScript job, at least not css only. :)